# Notifications in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, onesignal

How can I send a specific person a notification using OneSignal, I searched this topic and asked chatgpt4 and all the answers are old ,Important note: I do not want to send a notification to everyone, but rather I want to send a notification to one president

Comment: I think you use normal push notification such as firebase just use getToken which is very specific.So initially you set this for your user and store this to your backend then send notification based on this Token.

Comment: "One president"?